# google/wire: Is this a use case for the Singleton pattern?

Tags: go, dependency-injection

The following snippet declares two google/wire initializers which have a dependency in common. What is the best way to enforce that only one instance of the configuration is created?

I could pass the shared dependency down to the InitializeStorageHandler function, but that would defeat the purpose of DI if my understanding is correct.

Of course, I could also use the Singleton pattern. I'm not sure if this is the "Go-Way" of doing things. Is there a best practice?

```
package api

import (
    "../storage"
    "../config"
    "github.com/google/wire"
)

func InitializeServer() (*Server, error) {
    panic(wire.Build(config.NewConfiguration, NewServer))
}

func InitializeStorageHandler() *StorageHandler {
    panic(wire.Build(config.NewConfiguration, storage.NewStorage, storage.NewService, NewStorageHandler))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course, I could also use the Singleton pattern

That would be consistent with wire, as in [issue 77](https://github.com/google/wire/issues/77#issuecomment-426425710), which mentions that "Wire is very much designed for provision of singletons".

As discussed in [issue 21](https://github.com/google/wire/issues/21):

> Wire intentionally does not have a notion of subcomponents at the moment.
>   In talking with the **[Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger)** team, we discovered that subcomponents and scopes introduce a fair amount of complexity.
>
> As you say, you can get much the **same behavior by returning the singletons from the first injector that creates them and then pass them to later injectors**. This has the benefit of making the dataflow explicit, which for the examples we came up with, seemed like a net win.
>   That said, we're very curious to see how folks will use Wire in real-world applications: if this does not scale, we might have to revisit.
>
> I realized after looking more closely at [your sample](https://github.com/drewolson/dagger_maven_example/blob/singleton_across_providers/src/test/java/org/drewolson/theater/ProjectorTest.java) that the component itself is stateful (a detail I had forgotten about Dagger). My explanation above is still largely applicable: we want state to be explicit.

In that case, check out "[How singleton pattern works with Golang](https://medium.com/golang-issue/how-singleton-pattern-works-with-golang-2fdd61cd5a7f)" from [Jefferson Otoni Lima](https://twitter.com/jeffotoni): [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) or the [`init()` function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init) can help building a singleton securely, in a "Go-way".